# How to make private areas of a website (using php)?

Tags: php

I would like to make a secure admin panel to control parts of a website but I am not that experienced with PHP (or any other server scripting language) so I need help.
I know how to store user credentials in a database and how to verify if the credentials entered in a form match those, but not how to have a kind of secret area that only signed-in users can access. I have found examples for how to do this but they use `header` to redirect authenticated users to the admin panel (i.e. `admin.php`). Couldn't then a non-admin just go to `example.com/admin.php` and access everything? I'm not sure and this is basically the question I am asking.

Comment: Well you will need to use something like a session to make sure that the user is actually loggedin: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: You have it backwards. The admin pages should check whether the user is logged in as an admin. If they aren't, it redirects them to the regular page. So the non-admin can't just go to `admin.php`, because it will redirect them away.

Comment: Or it could just display an error message. The important thing is that it doesn't let them use the page.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials which can show you how to create a login system. Here's a half decent one which mostly follows good security practices (sadly unlike many available): https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-php-login-form--cms-33261

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy answer to this really but you need session cookies regardless.
Have a search on google for a "Simple php login form"

It can be done with either [$_COOKIE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) or [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

$_COOKIE is stored in the users browser.

$_SESSION is stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header("Location:~your path~");` to go back to home page or any page you want if you try open page by browser directly by url.

First:

You add **HTML** form that send anything to **PHP** you can only open page by submitting this form.

index.html:

```html
<a href="server.php" >go to server</a>
<!-- no request to server -->
<form action="server.php" method="post"  >
    <input hidden="hidden" name="req" value="true" >
    <input type="submit" value="go to server" >
</form>
<!-- sent post "true" to server so you can open private page-->
```

server.php:

```php
<?php

$req=$_POST["req"];//$req == "true" if you submit index.html form

if($req == "true") {
    echo "hello world";
} else {
     header("Location:index.html");
     /*
     if you put url for this page there 
     no post request so return to index.html
     */
}
```